# Tensorflow GPU - ImportError: Could not find 'nvcuda.dll'

Tags: python, tensorflow, scripting, anaconda

> ImportError: Could not find 'nvcuda.dll'. TensorFlow requires that
>   this DLL be installed in a directory that is named in your %PATH%
>   environment variable. Typically it is installed in
>   'C:\Windows\System32'. If it is not present, ensure that you have a
>   CUDA-capable GPU with the correct driver installed.

please solve this error i am doing FYP

Comment: what does FYP mean? Also this question is horribly vague but you should follow the instructions in the error and install CUDA drivers!

Comment: FYP mean final year project if nt mistaken.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, my computer does not have an Nvidia card. So I can not install CUDA driver. I downloaded `nvcuda.dll` and executed

```
regsvr32  C:\Windows\System32\nvcuda.dll
```

instruction, they  make a fire so as to compile all TensorFlow code that note

> ImportError: Could not find 'nvcuda.dll'.

Anyway, please reinstall your TensorFlow:

```
pip uninstall protobuf 
pip uninstall tensorflow
```

and then

```
pip install protobuf 
pip install tensorflow
```

Answer (score 2):

The error because , your system couldn't find CUDA enable for tensorflow-GPU version. Please refer link for installing tensorflow-GPU in [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_windows). If you want to access GPU version you have to install CUDA toolkit first. Make sure that when you are installing CUDA toolkit and cuDNN should support to your tensrflow version.